# Cannot Fully Create an OnBehalfOf Relationship using Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to follow the guide on the [Facebook OnBehalfOf Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/business-manager/guides/on-behalf-of/) and I am unable to properly get Step 2 and 3 to work properly.

When I complete step 2 I successfully receive an Access Token, however the SystemUser and App is not created on the Client Business.
When I try to use the /me endpoint on the newly created access token it does not return anything.

I have tried the following steps:

- I have generated a user access token via a facebook button login.
- I retrieve the Client Business Id via https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/act_ClientAdAccountId?fields=business&access_token=FacebookLoginButtonAccessToken
- I create an OnBehalfOf relationship between my business and the client business via https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/MyBusinessId/managed_businesses?existing_client_business_id=ClientBusinessId&access_token=FacebookLoginButtonAccessToken
- I fetch an access token from the client business via https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/ClientBusinessId/access_token?app_id=MyBusinessesAppId&scope=ads_management,business_management,pages_read_engagement,catalog_management&access_token=MyAdminSystemUserAccessToken

I am unsure if there's a permission issue going on, or if I have not understood a part above correctly and am making an incorrect call.